# SpriteKit | Double hit Explosion Bug

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift4, xcode9, 2d-games

I am currently working on the finishing touches of my Space Shooter. In this shooter you hit asteroids and when hit the an explosion animation is played. How ever later in the game when it gets faster and 2 asteroids show up on the screen at the same time and IF they explode at the same time the first explosion function will not complete leaving the last image shown before the second explosion on screen. This eventually piles up until there are so many nodes on the screen that the game crashes, despite the fact that it looks shitty.

My current code for the Explosion Function is:

```
func spawnEpxlotion(spawnPosition: CGPoint){

    let explosion1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "explosion-1")
    let explosion2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "explosion-2")
    let explosion3 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "explosion-3")
    let explosion4 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "explosion-4")
    let explosion5 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "explosion-5")
    let explosion6 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "explosion-6")
    let explosion7 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "explosion-7")
    let explosion8 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "explosion-8")
    let explosion9 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "explosion-9")

    let animateExplosion = SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0, withRange: 0),
        SKAction.animate(with: [explosion1,explosion2,explosion3,explosion4,explosion5,explosion6,explosion7,explosion8,explosion9], timePerFrame: 0.03)])

    explosion = SKSpriteNode(texture: explosion1)
    explosion.position = spawnPosition
    explosion.setScale(2)
    self.addChild(explosion)
    explosion.run(explosionSound)
    explosion.run(animateExplosion, completion : {self.explosion.removeFromParent()})
}
```

It all works like a charm until a double hit occurs. I tried a few possible fixes, but none of them did it. Most of them just turned off the explosion function all together, which is obviously not the goal.

If someone could help me with that that would be cool. Maybe there is a way to force complete a function regardless if it is called twice at the same time.

Comment: Does the animation get stuck at the same place every time the bug happens? If so, where?

Comment: It get's stuck where ever the Asteroid exploded. Different every time.

Comment: Oh, I mean, where in the code?

Comment: Well that's a good question, it basically doesn't complete this part of the function:

explosion.run(animateExplosion, completion : {self.explosion.removeFromParent()})

as the new explosion is called before it get's to the end of the function code

Comment: Does it always show the last image of the animation when it hangs? Never the first image or the middle image?

Comment: It shows what ever the last image of the animation was before the new explosion is called, sometimes explosion9, sometimes explosion 7, it all depends on when the new explosion was called.

Comment: Where is the variable `explosion` declared?

Comment: At the top just under class GameScene:

Comment: I think that's the problem. You're re-using it when you call the function a second time. Make it a local in the function. I think that's it

Comment: Awesome thanks, can you put that as an Answer and I will green tick it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `explosion` variable is not declared in your function, which suggests that it must be an instance variable. When you call `spawnEpxlotion` while the previous animation is still running, and you get to the line `explosion = SKSpriteNode(texture: explosion1)`, you're blowing away the node that was running the animation. Make `explosion` a local variable. Best of luck to you.